# python how to GOTO/REDO

Tags: python

I have a line in a function filter3 is a dict that I create via a shuffle function.

```
answer = shuffle(filter3)
print(answer)
userConfirm()
```

What I want to do is implement my userConfirm() function and if the user is unhappy with the output they select "N" and it will make answer go again.

Just not sure what to put in my "N" response in my function to make this happen.

```
import sys


def userConfirm():
    """get user confirmation to proceed"""
    userChoice = raw_input("Are you happy with results? (Y or N or Q): ")
    if userChoice == "N":
        #What to do here
    elif userChoice == "Q":
        sys.exit("You Quit the Program")
    elif userChoice == "Y":
        print("OK Proceeding")
```

Comment: You know what a loop is, right? use one...

Comment: @l4mpi         yes thats what I have done but I want to keep the logic from the 2 functions separate so that I could use the userConfirm() function elsewhere in my program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys

def userConfirm():
    userChoice = raw_input("Are you happy with results? (Y or N or Q): ")
    if userChoice == 'N':
        return False
    elif userChoice == 'Q':
        sys.exit("You Quit the Program")
    elif userChoice == 'Y':
        print "OK Proceeding"
        return True

while True:
    answer = shuffle(filter3)
    print answer
    if userConfirm():
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

`goto` is considered harmful since the end of the sixties.  Google for "goto considered harmful", there's an article by Dijkstra about that topic which became so famous that the phrase "considered harmful" nowadays is often reused for similar topics.

The reason is plain an simple: With `goto` you can create code which is hard to understand, hard to debug and hard to extend.

Use a proper loop for what you want.  Rethink your problem from "I want to go back under this condition" to "I want to repeat this until this condition is met."  Then writing it as a loop comes much easier and more natural.

Unfortunately, Python has no `repeat` … `until` for loops testing at the end.  You only have `for` loops (for a specific list of iterations to perform) and `while` loops which test at the beginning, not the end.  But you can use a `while True` for this and test explicitly in the end yourself:

```
while True:
  do_something()
  if break_condition:
    break
```

Your second issue (given only in the comment below your question) can be solved by letting `userConfirm()` `return` a value stating whether the user wishes a repetition or not:

```
def userConfirm():
  """get user confirmation to proceed"""
  userChoice = raw_input("Are you happy with results? (Y or N or Q): ")
  if userChoice == "N":
    return False
  elif userChoice == "Q":
    sys.exit("You Quit the Program")
  elif userChoice == "Y":
    print("OK Proceeding")
    return True

while True:
  do_something()
  if userConfirm():
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

***goto*** is always considered a bad programming practice after the advent of modern programming languages. It becomes hard to debug, track bugs/errors or even try to understand what in the hell you've written a few months ago(especially when your program deals with multiple nested if/else statements or loops). The best way to solve a problem without using ***goto*** is by structuring your program well. Grab a paper, design the structure. Now after you have a concrete plan with good logic, start coding. Use LOOPS, use BREAK and CONTINUE statements where necessary. These simple tricks/methods will help you build neat programs and save you from headaches. As they say *"weeks of coding saves you hours of paperwork"*.